# pushing to server broken after hard reset

Tags: git

I am new to git and am trying to set git up with http://danielmiessler.com/study/git/#website to manage my site. I am working using the git gui in win7

I have gotten things working, but for the wrong reasons ended up doing a git hard reset. Now although when I push the latest changes fro local to my website the IDE says it worked, no changes to the actual site on the remote server have occured.

here is an example message:

> ==[IDE]== Dec 3, 2012 2:15:38 PM Pushing
> git push ssh://****.com/home/*****/site_hub.git +refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
> Remote Repository Updates
> Branch : master
> Old Id : d8ad488e1d9f8db069cf2f93d289b7******
> New Id : c51319292573d3d159a628c73ca20844663b72db******
> Result : OK
>
> Local Repository Updates
> No update

when I go to the server's file manager, no files appear to have been updated today .

It was working fine before the hard reset. how can I fix this?

Comment: could be that you need to do a `git push -f` this will however remove all history from your server. so be sure to have a backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is telling you there are no changes in your local repository that are not already in the server.

```
git reset --hard
```

Will just delete what changes you have tracked in your local branch in between your last commit and the current state.

Do a

```
git log
```

And you will probably see that you have no committed changes.

You could also try a

```
git push --force <MYREMOTE> <MYBRANCH>
```

To replace the server branch with your current one, this will overwrite any changes on the server.